# What’s the difference between diskutil unmount and diskutil eject?

Tags: mac, command-line

On macOS (eg. Mojave 10.14), what is the difference between the `diskutil unmount` and `diskutil eject` commands?

For example, if I want to execute this from the command line (eg. bash in terminal), but I want to have the same, ‘safe’ result as though I had clicked the eject icon in the Finder:

- which command(s) should I use (and why)?
- what are the differences and side-effects between these two?

Answer (score 5):

You can at least be certain that `diskutil eject` does all that `diskutil unmount` does, plus (sometimes) more. Examples given in the man page mention removable media readers equipped with a motor to physically eject a volume, such as a CD-ROM player. Also, when there are more than one filesystem on the media, `diskutil eject` will unmount all volumes on the media, while `diskutil unmount` just unmounts the one filesystem you mention explicitly.

When in doubt, I'd always go for the `eject` verb.

Comment: This answer is possibly incomplete; corrections are welcome.

Comment: Since eject unmounts other volumes, it may not be the right ‘default’ action for everybody.

Comment: @samh Yes, that's one reason for writing “When in doubt”.

Answer (score 4):

You unmount a volume, and eject a drive. For non-removable media, eject and unmount are equivalent. If the media is removable, eject tells the OS the media is to be removed and the OS releases all links to the drive.   This question was asked on the apple discussion board and you can review the responses [here.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1545722)